# Как передать список в аргумент функции в Python?

Tags: python, список

**Есть такой код и в нем все работает так, как и должно быть:**

```
m=1000
t=10                                             #постоянная времени
x=[]
y=[]
for a in range(m):
    b=0
    if 300 < a < 700:
        b=1
    x.append(b)       
for n in range (m):
        imp=(1/t)*exp(-n/t)                      #имп. хар-ка для интегрирующей цепи
        h.append(imp)
    y=np.convolve(x,h)                           #операция свертки двух функций
print (x)
print (h)
print (y)
pp.plot(x) 
pp.plot(y)
pp.show()
```

**Теперь мне нужно запихнуть это все в функцию от аргумента - списка х**

**Вот, что я делаю:**

`def integrFiltr(x):
        for a in range(m):
            b=0
            if 300 < a < 700:
                b=1
            x.append(b)

        for n in range (m):
            imp=(1/t)*exp(-n/t)                      #имп. хар-ка для интегрирующей цепи
            h.append(imp)
        y=np.convolve(x,h) 
integrFiltr(x)`

**Теперь на выходе у меня получается пустой список y, и, следовательно, второй график не строится**

**Что не так?**

Comment: Исправьте табуляции, пожалуйста. И оформите второй фрагмент кода. Вы можете заключить весь код в `\`\`\`блок кода\`\`\``, сохранив при это все отступы исходного файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы функция изменяла переменные вне своего блока, их нужно объявить как глобальные:

```py
x, y = [], []
def integrFiltr():
    global x, y # теперь под этими названиями подразумеваются глобальные переменные
    # все остальные действия функции тут

integrFiltr()
```

Однако, такой подход менее предпочтителен, чем следующий:

```py
x, y = [], []
def integrFiltr(x, y):
    # все действия вашей функции тут
    return x, y

x, y = integrFiltr(x, y)
```

Разумеется, если функции нужны не только `x` и `y`, но и другие переменные, их нужно указывать как глобальные при первом подходе, или же как параметры при втором (и передавать при вызове, соответственно). Притом в `return` их писать не нужно, если функция не должна их менять

Comment: Отлично, я понял, спасибо большое)